# Eclipse won't load workbench

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

Eclipse won't load any of the .java files in my /Users/my_name/Desktop/Go directory. Eclipse just goes straight to an empty workbench. Anybody know what the problem might be?

Comment: Have you imported the source/project to the workspace?

Comment: How do you expect eclipse to know about this directory? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Eclipse you must create a workspace and import any Java files you want to use in to a Java project. It will not just work with a directory containing Java files.

Use 'File > New > Java Project' to create the Java project.

Use 'File > Import... > General > File System' to import the Java files.